# RelativeSourceBinding Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight

I am trying to use relative source biding with a combobox, the binding it self is working and the data gets loaded correctly, but I can't get something similar to DisplayMemberBinding for relative source binding that works.

Code:

```
<ComboBox MinWidth="60" Margin="5,0,0,0" >
    <local:BindingHelper.Binding>
        <local:BindingList>
            <local:RelativeSourceBinding Path="IncPOCYesNo" TargetProperty="ItemsSource" BindingMode="TwoWay" RelativeMode="ParentDataContext" />
            <!--<local:RelativeSourceBinding Path="CurrentIncidentDetail.ExistingProcedure" TargetProperty="SelectedValue" BindingMode="TwoWay" RelativeMode="ParentDataContext" />-->
         </local:BindingList>
     </local:BindingHelper.Binding>
</ComboBox>
```

IncYesNo is a class with properties Name and Id

When I run it as is the ComboBox Displays Namespace.IncYesNo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,

why do you put binding path as your class, it should be the collection. Let me assume it as a list.

```
<ComboBox >
    <local:BindingHelper.Binding>
        <local:BindingList>
            <local:RelativeSourceBinding Path="List<IncPOCYesNo>" TargetProperty="ItemsSource"/>
        </local:BindingList>
    </local:BindingHelper.Binding>
</ComboBox>
```

[RelativeSource Binding](http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/)